# doctrine:generate:entities - Cannot redeclare <function name>

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have an existing database which I successfully imported into a symfony2 bundle using `doctrine:mapping:import`.

The tables uses underscore naming. One of the tables has this two columns:

```
- ab_desc  
- abd_esc
```

After importing, the properties are converted to camelCase and looks like this

```
- $abDesc
- $abdEsc
```

which is absolutely ok, since PHPs variables are case sensitive.

But if I now try to generate entities using `doctrine:generate:entities`
doctrine tries to create this to methods:

```
- function getabDesc()
- function getabdEsc()
```

which leads to the error

```
cannot redclare "getabDesc()"
```

since PHPs functions are case INsensitive...

I can now write the getters and setters on my own, but I was wondering if there is a better solution like telling doctrine to use underscore properties or something like that.

Comment: one thing that comes up with me is to forget the getters and setters and to make the properties public instead of private.

Comment: @Frankbeen Doctrine doesn't work well with public properties.

Comment: You could be right Gerry. I always use getters and setters and logic property names.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(table="ab")
 */
class Ab {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="ab_desc")
     */
    protected $abDesc;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="abd_desc")
     */
    protected $abdDesc;

    public getAbDesc() {
        return $this->abDesc;
    }

    public getAbdDesc() {
        return $this->abdDesc;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. My properties are  
`$abDesc` and `$abdEsc`. 
Same name but different use of capital and small letters.

Comment: I always create getters and setters. And I always follow this simple rule: get + capitalized property name and set + capitalized peoperty name. At anotations I can set what will be field name at the table, this name can be totally different from property name.